# how to trigger a scheduled exception in java?

Tags: java, timeout, scheduled-tasks, schedule

I want to throw a timeoutException after x millis.

I have tried this code,
but it requires `try-catch` in the `run()` method.

```
    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            throw new TimeoutException("test time: expected:"+expectedTimeMilli);
        }
    } ;
    new Timer().schedule(timerTask, 0L);
```

how can i trigger a scheduled exception in java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot throw java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException from run() because it does not allow to throw checked exceptions, use a RuntimeException instead. You can create your own TimeoutException which will extends RuntimeException

Comment: how come it allows to throw `throw new RuntimeException();` without declaring in `run()` signature?

Comment: @EladBenda Runtime exception are unchecked exception . Thats why no need to declare